# Article citation tracking

Tags: citations, journals, journal-workflow

I am trying to find the origin of an idea based on journal articles.

**To elaborate more**:

Let's say object A affects object B in a certain manner and this was originally discovered by Researcher A a long time ago, say in the 1960s.

Subsequently, until now, there are many variations of studies around the idea that object A affects object B. Many journal articles revolving around this central idea have been published.

**My dilemma is:**

I do not know who (i.e. Researcher A) or which was the original paper published regarding this idea.  Is there any facility/journal resources that allow me to track the origin of this particular idea? Does Scopus have such a citation tracking ability?

Answer (score 3):

There are no such online databases that could track down origins of ideas. To understand why a citation is used you have to read the paper. To get to the bottom of an idea you might have to follow several pathes of citations.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to track the origin of an idea (unless it is patented). In order to do so you would have to traverse along towards the root of the citation graph. Which might not be practical since not all such references along this path may be freely available. You may go trough the trouble if the core of your research depends on this method's origin. But if you wish to design a system that is to be better than the ones in literature, then you ought to look for the recently published best practices and state of the art. In such a case the notion of who invented the method would be irrelevant.

Note that if you are still concerned about the originator of the concept there are a few tips you can follow. If this concept is revolutionary in its time then you might see many articles citing the same historic paper.  If such a concept is of common understanding then you might not see such a paper in common cited with the ones you studied. In such a case searching for the originator would be futile. This applies provided that you did enough survey to attain an extensive number of papers under this concept.